# Extracting the nearest date prior to a fixed date in r

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, lubridate

I have a dataset, `df` as follows:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
                 ID INDEX_DATE  DATE    VALUE
                 1  14/06/2017  16/02/2015  7
                 1  14/06/2017  16/02/2015  6.5
                 1  14/06/2017  21/07/2015  7
                 1  14/06/2017  08/09/2015  9.5
                 1  14/06/2017  04/12/2015  8.9
                 1  14/06/2017  28/01/2016  8.4
                 1  14/06/2017  30/03/2016  8.2
                 1  14/06/2017  25/05/2016  7.6
                 1  14/06/2017  17/08/2016  8.2
                 1  14/06/2017  16/11/2016  8
                 1  14/06/2017  18/01/2017  8.8
                 1  14/06/2017  24/03/2017  9.1
                 1  14/06/2017  14/06/2017  7.9
                 1  14/06/2017  14/06/2017  8.0
                 2  10/01/2017  26/03/2015  7.4
                 2  10/01/2017  26/03/2015  7.7
                 2  10/01/2017  14/04/2016  7
                 2  10/01/2017  03/04/2017  7.6
                 3  14/01/2015  06/05/2015  7.2
                 3  14/01/2015  29/07/2015  7.1
                 3  14/01/2015  18/11/2015  7.2
                 3  14/01/2015  17/02/2016  7.3
                 3  14/01/2015  03/08/2016  7.3
                 4  08/12/2016          NA  NA
                 ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I would like to extract the `VALUE` that corresponds to the nearest `DATE` prior to the `INDEX_DATE` for each `ID`. If there is no `DATE` prior to the `INDEX_DATE`, then the nearest `DATE` after `INDEX_DATE` will be used instead.

There are 3 cases:

1. `ID == 1`: Only has `DATE`s prior to (or same date as) the `INDEX_DATE`
2. `ID == 2`: Has `DATE`s before and after the `INDEX_DATE`
3. `ID == 3`: Only has `DATE`s after the `INDEX_DATE`

If the chosen `DATE` has more than 1 value, I would randomly choose any of them.

My desired output:

```
df2 <- read.table(text = "
                 ID INDEX_DATE  DATE    VALUE
                 1  14/06/2017  14/06/2017  7.9
                 2  10/01/2017  14/04/2016  7
                 3  14/01/2015  06/05/2015  7.2
                 4  08/12/2016          NA  NA
                 ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I tried to write my code but it would not work on the second case (i.e. `ID == 2`):

```
library(lubridate); library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(INDEX_DATE, DATE), funs(dmy)) %>%
  mutate(DATEDIFF = (INDEX_DATE - DATE)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(PRIORPOST = if_else(any(DATEDIFF >= 0), "PRIOR", "POST_ONLY"),
         CHOSEN_VALUE = if_else(PRIORPOST == "PRIOR" & DATEDIFF >= 0 & DATEDIFF == min(DATEDIFF), VALUE, 
                        if_else(PRIORPOST == "POST_ONLY" & DATEDIFF < 0 & DATEDIFF == max(DATEDIFF), VALUE, NA_real_))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(CHOSEN_VALUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope this help :

```
library(dplyr)  
df$INDEX_DATE <- as.Date(df$INDEX_DATE, format="%d/%m/%Y")
df$DATE <- as.Date(df$DATE, format="%d/%m/%Y")
df$minDay <- abs(difftime(df$INDEX_DATE, df$DATE, units="days")) #Calculate the nearest day.

index <- 1
for (i in 1:length(unique(df$ID))) {
  temp <- subset(df, ID==unique(df$ID)[i])
  temp <- temp[temp$minDay == min(temp$minDay),] #Extract the minimum day of each ID.
  if (nrow(temp) > 1) {temp <- temp[sample(nrow(temp),1),]} else {temp <- temp} #Randomly pick 1 row.
  temp <- temp[, -5] #Remove minDay
  if (index == 1) { #Combine each ID's minimum row
    output <- temp
    index <- 0
  } else {
    output <- rbind(output, temp)
  }
}
output
```